# Why does XOR swap algorithm fail if variables are the same storage location, but not if variables are the same values

Tags: algorithm, swap, xor

If I use XOR swap algorithm with the same values, swapping doesn't fail:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x = 10, y = 10;

  x = x ^ y;
  y = x ^ y;
  x = x ^ y;

  printf("After Swapping: x = %d, y = %d", x, y); // prints "After Swapping: x = 10, y = 10"

  return 0;
}
```

If I use pointers, swapping fails (x will be zero):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    *xp = *xp ^ *yp;
    *yp = *xp ^ *yp;
    *xp = *xp ^ *yp;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  swap(&x, &x);
  printf("After swap(&x, &x): x = %d", x); // prints x == 0
  return 0;
}
```

Should the algorithm fail with the same value? If I just use Boolean algebra, swapping will fail when I do first XOR operation (the first argument will become zero).

EDIT: made clearer what "it fails" means

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? Doesn't compile? Produces the wrong output? Sets your computer on fire?

Comment: Have you considered aliasing? xp and yp point to the same object. Try with two variables instead (and probably 2 different values: x *and* y being 10 doesn't tell you that values have been swapped).

Comment: You should actually avoid swap via xor. Because, it will fail for the same pointer value, and for `float` or `double` values.

Comment: You can not do a bitwise operation on `double` or `float` data type. right? And I was saying this on the comment. Because, this is not an answer, It's a suggestion. @MrSmith42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's run both cases step-by-step.

Case #1: 2 variables, same values

```
x          y
10         10
*run x = x^y*
0          10
*run y = x^y*
0          10
*run x = x^y*
10         10
```

As in this case, `y` location holds the value, it is able to produce the correct result. Now, lets see case #2.

Case #2: One location, say x.

```
xp = &x     yp = &x
10          10
run *xp = *xp ^ *yp;
0           0            //the value at xp is changed but since locations xp and yp are same, pointing to variable x, both will hold same values at all times.
```

And for all future statements, 0^0 gives 0. And hence the o/p.

Comment: The last line in case #1 should be `10      10`.